# How can I get Greek bold letters?

Tags: fonts, greek, boldmath

I like to wrap linear algebra (matrices/vectors) with `\mathbf{}`. However, this doesn't appear to work with Greek letters (and who knows what else?). Is there a fix for this?

I'm open to a range of solutions; even introducing a new font family. What I don't want to do is simply fall back on `\bm`.

Comment: What is wrong with `\bm`? Perhaps you should be a bit more specific in what exactly it is you want.

Comment: It's not terrible. I just like to make the type distinction visibly striking.

Comment: That all depends on the font being used. Note that `\mathbf` produces upright bold letters. If that is what you are looking for with greek, then you should mention this in your question. I generally use `\bm` because it is bold italic, and using this as a vector, then it make sense that the items of `\bm{x}` are `x_i` with an italic `x`.

Comment: That's a good argument. But then what's the purpose of `\mathbf{}` if you always have to worry about Greek letters ruining your consistency?

Comment: I'm guessing tradition. Remember LaTeX comes from a time with large limits and resources and especially fonts, probably something to do with which font and which slots it looks in. There are many of the math font macros that only supports a limited number of inputs, `\mathbf` is no different.

Answer (score 5):

The `unicode-math` package supports `\mathbf`, as well as the newer commands `\symbfup` and `\symbfit` to specify upright and slanted bold math letters.  These also have aliases such as `\mbfitalpha` (mathematical bold italic alpha). In addition, if a math font comes in a bold version (like XITS Math Bold and Libertinus Math Bold), you can use its glyphs with `\boldmath` and `\boldsymbol`.

If you are required to use legacy 8-bit fonts, the `isomath` package has a good selection of OML alphabets that include Greek, and `mathastext` has the ability to load LGR-encoded Greek fonts.

Comment: Can you please add a full example so that future reader can get help from your answer?

Answer (score 2):

I absolutely agree with the opinion of the user @dailef. However, I think that you could also try this code with packages `amsmath, amssymb`. This code contains another two possible alternatives (see code).

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}
\[\text{ First option: }\, \boldsymbol{\alpha}, \boldsymbol{\beta}\]
\[\text{ Second (same output) option: }\, \mbox{\boldmath$\gamma$}, \mbox{\boldmath$\delta$} \]
\end{document}
```

There is also a package that generate a fake-bold symbol called `amsbsy`. Just as example you can see this screenshot.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsbsy}
\begin{document}
\[\text{ A fake--bold symbol: }\, \pmb{\alpha}, \pmb{\beta}\]
\end{document}
```

With `amsbsy` you can objectively see where I have inserted the yellow arrows as the alpha and beta symbols have come closer to generate a bold symbol.

Comment: I would assume that this is what `\bm` uses when available.

Comment: @daleif Yes of course.

Comment: `\usepackage{bm}` (to be loaded after `amsmath`) is recommended. It uses `\bm`, but makes `\boldsymbol` an alias to it, so already written code need not be changed except for loading `bm`.

Comment: @egreg With lot of sincerity I use also for my notes `\usepackage{bm}`. I wanted to give to OP another solutions without to use `\bm` to have bold symbols and I want not to copy the same solution of others users.